Find the fault in this approach else its saving 33% of Brachistocrone curve and 12.5% in storing volume in sphere but with same result!

PART 1
In a bid to get the same effect as a Brachistocrone curve for a given dimension with same time of descent but with a smaller one, the gravity assisted projectile motion patches up perfectly to save 33% of the curve length.
If the calculations are correct, then the 3D figure formed by rotating the curve along vertical axis can serve as a good rain water collector at the origin
PART 2
In a bid to store water in a sphere with mazimum volume/surface area, the sphere if open at 30degree elevation with center stores proportionately 12.5% more water than semisphere or a full sphere.
To display the Volume/Surface-Area as a function of angle from the vertical, the grapth at https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8vbdbpnlvj shows that for angle = 2*pi/3, it stores a maximum of 12.5% more
Please the concerned people comment on the whole premise/calculations!

How are part 1 and part 2 related?

The very first line of calculation is incorrect because $\sqrt{a+b} \neq \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}$.

I'd suggest the OP to remove the part related to the sphere, which could be the object of another question. And to insert the calculations into the text, written with MathJax.

There's an error in your formulas: descent time for the cycloid is $\pi\sqrt{H/(2g)}$, one half of the time you used in your computation. That changes the value $H/h$ you found.

It is not obvious (and in fact it's false) that the projectile will end its path exactly where the large cycloid ends.
